# How can I jump to signs in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

There are a couple of plugins that add *signs* (see `:h sign`) marking syntax errors in various files. In particular, the Vim-Latex-Suite adds syntax error signs in latex files, and the Drupal Vim plugin adds them in PHP files:

[image: Vim signs]

Is there any way to jump to these signs? I've read the docs, and I can't see anything, and `:cnext` etc. don't work, because signs aren't errors. Not being able to jump can be quite annoying, as it means you have to scroll through the whole document looking for the red arrows on the left column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on which plugins you're using.   (Which you supplied later...)

The Syntastic plugin provides signs with links in the location list.

Try using 'll/ln/lp' to see & move through the location list of the error signs

Comment: The scripts I have installed are: `calendar NrrwRgn snipmate.vim tagbar VimOrganizer VOoM CSApprox drupal nerdtree screen syntastic vim-latex Vim-R-plugin`. I don't think any of these other than the drupal and Vim-latex plugins are likely to affect this though. Perhaps there's some intermediate functionality of vim that these plugins use that uses signs?

Comment: Hey, I just tried `:ll`, and it works! Hadn't heard of the location list before. Maybe you wann re-jig your answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: Ha!  From the Syntastic plugin:  Errors are loaded into the location list for the corresponding window.   Taa Daa!!